# Fastest way to get ResultSet to private strings?

Tags: java

I have a class that gets ran every time an action happens, for example, I log in and the User class gets ran. This class is passed a `ResultSet` containing information of that particular user.

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the result and split them into "class variables" (I believe they're called fields). I've tried the following:

```
public User(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    this.username = resultSet.getString("username");
    this.firstname = resultSet.getString("firstname");
    // etc etc.
}
```

and that works, but since I have about two dozen elements in there, this would become a long list.

I also thought of a method where I'd look through the results and then check if its a string for example. If it is, assign it to a variable which name corresponds to the key, but that would cut my problem in half, since I'd still need to declare all those variables.

I was wondering if there's a faster, perhaps more elegant way to tackle something like this.

Thanks.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do. What performance issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: It sounds as if you're trying to glean User info upon successful login. Is this correct?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I misformatted the question a little. Is it clearer now?

Comment: May I recommend changing your local variable `set` to something else like `resultSet` or `rs` as `set` is quite confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it @Popeye

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you create a class for each type of information you retrieve from the database.  You created a User class for user information.  There's no shortcut where your database tables create Java objects, unless you use an ORM like Hibernate.

Comment: You could just store your data in an array of the size of the table-rows and loop over the columns of the result set. However, that is neither elegant, faster, or more readable than what you have. ORM is more elegant, but not "faster"

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'll look in to Hibernate. Could you post this as an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: Yes, to make this more elegant you'll need to rely on a library or roll your own. Hibernate is the popular ORM. You could also use a smaller library like JDBI (http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_queries/), but you'll end up writing more mapping code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a class for each type of information you retrieve from the database. You created a User class for user information. There's no shortcut where your database tables create Java objects, unless you use an ORM like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/).

Answer (score 0):

I have been recently working on a simple tool that does this. It accepts a `Map<String, Object>` and a class, and returns an instance of this class. Have look at [my repository](https://github.com/Jarcionek/Map-To-Object-Converter) for examples. If you use Maven, you can just add a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>uk.co.jpawlak</groupId>
    <artifactId>map-to-object-converter</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This will of course require you to convert `ResultSet` into `Map` first, however this is pretty simple and you will only have to write this code once.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box to help you accomplish something like that. 
There are couple of ways you could do it

1. Using ORM would be the best option - if you are willing to spend the time and effort to configure and set up the framework and update your objects as necessary.
2. Using Java reflection along with ResultSetMetaData to map the resultSet directly to Objects would be another option. Something along these lines http://oprsteny.com/?p=900

If you are lucky enough to have the object's field names exactly match the sql column names, like in your example, you could write something like this

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException; 
 ...    
private void getUserDetails(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, NoSuchFieldException, 
    SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,  IllegalAccessException {

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int i = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    // *this* being the user object
                    String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                    Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(colName);
                    field.set(this, resultSet.getObject(colName));

                }
            }
        }
```